# WPF sliderbar value to label

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have a max value on the slider bar of 25 and i want the label to change when a certain value on the slider bar is set

e.g

```
sliderbar.value[0] = lable.text "A";
sliderbar.value[1] = lable.text "B";
```

etc all the way to Z

Comment: You are not satisfied with my answer? If not, then ask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider  Maximum="25" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl" FontSize="24"></Label>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Here is the code:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e) {
            int asciiCode = (int) e.NewValue + 65;
            lbl.Content = (char) asciiCode;
        }
    }
```

So, you just make a shift by 65. ASCII codes of characters A-Z are from 65 to 90.
You can just make a cast from int into char.